# specify the name of country using longitude and latitude on android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using google api 15 on android emulator.

I want to specify a country from a map by using a touch to the screen,
So if I made a touch to the screen on some longitude and latitude, I can know to what country or a city those belong to?

.. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you try anything? If so, share the code or idea you tried. If you want to depend on google api, you need to reverse geocode and take the country part from the result.

Comment: Ok, I forget to include my try,, Thanks for ur note, yes I found a solution at last like u said by reverse geo-coding :) :).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
public static String getCountryName(Context context, double latitude, double longitude) {
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address> addresses = null;
    try {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
        Address result;

        if (addresses != null && !addresses.isEmpty()) {
            return addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
        }
        return null;
    } catch (IOException ignored) {
       //do something
    }

}
```

Comment: @Cristian I was wondering if you could help me with this question http://goo.gl/d5opg5 . It's not one of those "fix-this-for-me" questions, I promise.

Comment: This does not work all the time. It is not working on some Android devices. Not sure why getFromLocation is not retrieving an address all the time.

Comment: for what purpose did u use 'result'??